# Maya Python Playblast Progress Bar

Tags: python, maya

I have created a script that does playblast, I have made a little Ui also for that just to show the progress of the playblast, but I am unable to figure out how to bind that progress bar with the script, thus asking for little help here.

Here is the Playblast Script

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os
srtfrm = cmds.getAttr('defaultRenderGlobals.startFrame')
endfrm = cmds.getAttr('defaultRenderGlobals.endFrame')
filePath = cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)
fileName = os.path.basename(filePath)
plbPath = filePath.replace(fileName,"")
cmds.playblast(f=plbPath+fileName[:-3], fo=True, fmt='qt', c='H.264', w=1280, h=720, p=100, qlt=100, orn=False, st=srtfrm, et=endfrm, v=False, os=True)
```

And Here Is the UI

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds
winID= 'PlayblastUI'
if cmds.window(winID, exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI(winID)
window = cmds.window(winID, title='Make Playblast', resizeToFitChildren=True, sizeable=False, tlb=True )
cmds.columnLayout()
progressControl = cmds.progressBar(maxValue=100, width=325)
cmds.setParent('..')
cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfRows=1,rowHeight=(5,5))
cmds.setParent('..')
cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
cmds.button( label='Playblast', w = 200, command='cmds.progressBar(progressControl, edit=True, step=1)' )
cmds.text(label='     AnD CGI © 2020', font='smallPlainLabelFont')
cmds.setParent('..')
cmds.showWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the docs for the progressbar ([progressbar help](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2020/ENU/?guid=__CommandsPython_index_html)) command the command has to be called with a step size during the execution of the progress, in your case during the creation of the playblast. Since the playblast command itself does not allow to use a callback during blasting, you could try to use a scriptJob which is called during frame updates or an expression which is executed for every frame.

Comment: Well whatever you said I have already searched, I was looking for an example close to my situation or the same, thanks for the help though.